# Mapbox Geocoder ignores country

Tags: geocoding, mapbox

I'm trying to implement Geocoding with Mapbox. To get better results I want to limit my search to one country. I found [this guide](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=JavaScript#response-format) on how to do that. 
But unfortunatly when I do it in my code:

```
$(document).on('keyup', "#place", 
function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text.length >= 5) {
      geocoder.query({query:text, country:'de'}, setMap());
    }
```

it seems to ignore the country-options and searches worldwide...

Check out this minimal [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ukg30hc/).

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wrote the Mapbox Support Team. Unfortunatly limitation by country is not (yet) support via geocode.query. 
But you can use country limited search via the [API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=JavaScript#introduction).